# How to list my name in publications, given that I am referred to by my middle name?

Tags: publications, personal-name

I prefer to be referred to by my middle name. How should I list my name on publications?

I'm not sure if this is correct, but in the past I have written: First initial. Middle name Last name.

Comment: Reminds me of three distinguished lunar scientists who always used their middle name. When they coauthored a review with a third author, they made him use his middle name too as a joke. All three were named Taylor, resulting in the paper [The Moon: A Taylor perspective](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0016703706006132). Note how they write their name - exactly as you offered.

Answer (score 26):

You can write your name however you prefer, so long as it is clear and consistent.

A good example of a person with your same situation, however, is [Chris Anderson at Berkeley](http://andersonlab.qb3.berkeley.edu/), whose publications list:

> J. Christopher Anderson

As you can see, he has come to the exact same solution that you suggest.

Comment: Just remember that once you've chosen a name, you should stick with it as much as possible—at least as far as publications are concerned!

Comment: @aeismail That's a wise advice in any situation ;)

Comment: I'd suggest leaving off the initial.  I think it was (mystery writer) Lawrence Block who pointed out that just about everyone in public life who used a leading initial is a fairly despicable person.  E.g. J. Edgar Hoover, E. Howard Hunt...

Comment: @jamesqf I guess you didn't like [Babylon 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Michael_Straczynski)?

Comment: Like other great writers such as F. Scott Fitzgerald or L. Ron Hubbard.

Comment: L. Ron Hubbard. Right.